# How to remove prerelease designation on nuget package?

Tags: continuous-integration, nuget, semantic-versioning

I'm looking on creating NuGet packages as part of my CI builds.  My intent is to be able to deploy the final application for testing, and once passed, allow that build to be promoted to a release version by removing the -prerelease designation.  How can I take an existing NuGet prerelease package and convert it to a non prerelease?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if the package contain the hash file that is causing an issue. I think your only choice is to generate a new package.

Comment: Well, I tried doing that manually and the package couldn't be installed anymore as NuGet thought it was invalid.

Comment: I've confirmed that removing all traces of the prerelease tag isn't enough, other changes seem to be needed.

Comment: Apparently, things have changed. I tested it and realized it does not work as I described above. I wonder if the package contain the hash file that is causing an issue. I think your only choice is to generate a new package.

Comment: If you rewrite your answer based on your latest comment, I'd remove my down vote and probably accept it, as that seems to be only option here.  In case, it's look like I'll just create the "final" package at the same time as the prerelease and just keep it in TeamCitys artifacts folder, and when I want to promote, I'll pull from the approprate build #s artifacts.

Comment: I made the change as you asked. I like your idea of generating the release package at the same time. If you are hosting your packages on the internal nuget feed, then you can push the release package after pre-release one is confirmed to valid.

Answer (score 1):

Just open the nupkg file in Package Explorer and edit the version number.

I have done that many times to covert a -rc to production.

Works fine

Comment: Don't think that helps in an automated build.